# HTML DSL placeholder insert cannot be called with argument supplied

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-dsl, kotlin-html-builder

I am building a few Html Templates using Kotlin DSL templating: https://ktor.io/docs/html-dsl.html#templates

But, something doesn't make sense in my approach:

```
class LayoutTemplate() : Template<HTML> {
    val titleText = Placeholder<FlowContent>()
    val header = TemplatePlaceholder<FlowContent>()
    val footer = TemplatePlaceholder<FlowContent>()

    override fun HTML.apply() {
        head {
            title {
                insert(titleText)
            }
        }

        body {
            insert(HeaderTemplate(), header)
            h1 {
                insert(titleText)
            }
            div {
                id = "content"
                insert(content)
            }
            insert(FooterTemplate(), footer)
        }
    }
}

class HeaderTemplate : Template<BODY> {
    override fun BODY.apply() {
        div {
            id = "header"
            h1 { +"Header" }
        }
    }
}

class FooterTemplate : Template<BODY> {
    override fun BODY.apply() {
        div {
            id = "footer"
            h1 { +"Footer" }
        }
    }
}
```

But, I get an error on `insert(HeaderTemplate(), header)` like: **None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.**

Similarly `insert(titleText)` shows:

**Type mismatch. Required: FlowContent Found: TITLE**

Can someone help on what I am not understanding?

Comment: Check the signature of insert in Template.kt. Update like below will solve some of your error
    val titleText = Placeholder<TITLE>()
    val header = TemplatePlaceholder<HeaderTemplate>()
    val footer = TemplatePlaceholder<FooterTemplate>()

Comment: Thank you that helped. Some documentation on the small details would really help for this DSL lib